# lower the overall download speed of the webpage when fetching thumbnails... how?

Tags: php, mysql, thumbnails

I am fetching many thumbnails in my application from a database/remote server and loading these in a list View (ul).
When there are, around, 100 thumbnails, the overall dowload speed of the webpage is reasonable, but when i am fetching around 250 + thumbnails, the overall download speed is noticeable slower...

I know that I could use pagination, but in my case, that is not an option...

The total number of thumbnails I will end up fetching is around 500... It will not get higher...

My question is the following:
Is there a way I could speed up the fetching of thumbnails in my application? I heard about maybe caching the thumbnails in a file and then calling that file... is that the best solution? if yes, can somebody guide me on that issue...

Any hints?  Thank you in advance.

Marco

### EDITED

what about using something that i've read... something similar to the following method:

```
$cache = 'cache/thumbnails.cache.php';

if (!file_exists($cache)) { // check also for the expiration date

   echo "this is a cached copy... <br />";
   include($cache);

} else

   // start the output buffer
   ob_start();

   // INSERT php script to show thumbnails...

    $fh = fopen($cache, 'w+') or die ('Error...');
    fwrite($fh, ob_get_contents());
    fclose($fh);

    // send the output to the browser
    ob_end_flush();

}
```

is that a recommended method?

Comment: Are you storing your thumbnails in your database, or in files ? Do you do one *(or more)* query per thumbnail, or just one query to list all rows at once ?

Comment: my images are in the file folder.. Only one query (per category) to list all rows at once. the url looks like this http://www.webpage.com/discography/albums?cat=n" ... the query: SELECT ... from ... WHERE cat = n

Answer (score 0):

Load the thumbnails as the user scroll down the page. 
Make the page dynamic, when the user is next to the bottom, you load more 4 rows of thumbnails for example.

The way you're doing you're probably using a lot of unnecessary bandwith of the other server, as the user may not look the latest thumbnails at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to collect all the thumbs, which btw need not be the same size or orientation, into one giant img and download just that image instead of 250 images. Then, to show the thumbs, you can position the giant img, as a background-image:, on its x and y axes such that the exact thumbnail you want shows up as the background image where you want it. Then the database cell for each image would hold just the thumb's size (maybe), its orientation (also maybe), and the x/y coordinates of your target thumbnail on the giant image.

Read up on css background-image for more.

-- pete

Comment: yea... i thought of that also... unfortunately, my thumbs are not all the same size....

Comment: @Marco: @Pete's answer works even for differently-sized pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Why is pagination not an option? I would assume this is the best option since all browsers will he able to use it instead of a dynamic page ajax load.

Are the images constantly changing? If not create a static page.

The next option is what you stated, caching the images. However, this will invlove the same skills required to create a static page.

Another option is to cache the page. You can estimate the frequency with which the page images change if they do and use that as the lifetime. A good, fast simple to use tool is php pear's cachelite.
With this you can always load the 500 images. 
An improvement will be to give the page a long lifetime and on page load check for changes in the database. You can them either rebuild the cache or serve the cached page.

Comment: one remark that i've notice is that once the thumbnails are fetched once, the browsers make a pretty good job when i'm fetching them again... i guess it's because browsers use the images that are cached on my drive...

Comment: i've edited my question above... what about the method using ob_start(); ? is that an ok method to use ?

Comment: The fact that the browser is caching the image does but mean your page will always be cached. The best thing is to implement the system yourself to reduce  server load and resource use. 
If advise against buffering with obstart. It does nothing to speed up the page and with 500plus images, your application can run out of memory really really fast!